# Отношение родителя и ребенка в структуре JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Структура: AnchorPane, внутри него imageView, к AnchorPane применен setOnMouseClicked(), к imageView тоже, и когда я нажимаю на imageView срабатывает mouseEvent картинки, а после и панельки. Можно ли как то сделать, чтобы mouseEvent реагировал только на imageView.
P.S. setOnAction не работает для imageView

Answer (score 0):

как вариант запихните картинку в элемент у которого есть setOnAction и его уже в AnchorPane
(изучаю java 1,5 недели)

Comment: такой себе вариант на самом деле))

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```java
ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image("resources/rewrite.png"));
image.setFitWidth(20);
image.setFitHeight(20);
image.setOpacity(0.3);
rewriteButton.graphicProperty().setValue(image);
```

уже здесь setOnAction() есть